# How to use onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.createElement to add React components to an existing html. I can see the button I created inside the div I am returning but my button does not respond onClick. Below is the code I am using :

```
const e = React.createElement;

function Button(props) {
  return e( 'button', {onClick:props.handleClick}, props.name)
}

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('ciao');
  }

  render() {
    return e('div', null,
                 e(Button, {handleClick:this.handleClick, name:'Get'},null))
  }
}

//const domContainer = document.querySelector('#getButton');

ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton,null,null),
                document.querySelector('#getButton'));
```

I cannot figure out why the code is not working. There are no errors in the log so I really have no idea.

Comment: any specific reason not using jsx ?

Comment: It is working as it should. https://codesandbox.io/s/wqjzxp4yx8

Comment: Wondering why are you still using initial version of react syntax

Comment: The code logs `ciao` as it should. Maybe you have activated any filter in your developer console? E.g. only showing errors instead of all logs?

Comment: Thanks guys! For some reason I cannot see it even if I don't have any filter activated. This was the fastest way I found to integrate react with the existing project. I've seen jsx but can you use it by just using cdn links in the project and not having to start a different project from zero? @DhavalPatel

Comment: The reason the button was not working is because inside the old html, there are angular elements. More precisely, I had my div inside another div that had angular element. What I did was to leave only by own div with it's button and it works! 

Thank1!

Answer (score 0):

[Your example works](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9xr3ol3l5)

Are you sure there is a dom element with the id `#getButton`?

As for using JSX: you have to set up your project so that [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) transpiles it.

Comment: I think I found the reason why. I tried my code elsewhere and it works. The reason is (probably) the fact that I was using a div with angular properties and it was probably making things bad.